# JS output option selection value as get parameter in link

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu, get

I have a dropdown list...

```
<select name="selection">
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
</select>
```

...and below that dropdown list is a link which opens an iframe in a Fancybox.

```
<a href="iframe_content.php?selection={selection of dropdown list}" data-fancybox data-options='{"type" : "iframe", "iframe" : {"preload" : true, "css" : {"width" : "500px", "height" : "400px", "overflow" : "hidden"}}}'>
    Click
</a>
```

As you can see the link has a GET parameter (selection=...) which should dynamically set whatever is currently selected in the dropdown as the parameter value, without reloading the page.

I know how to print a dropdown value inside a div or a span which has a class or an id. But I don't know how to do that as a part of a link i.e. an attribute value.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can print the dropdown value in the div then that's great. now you can get the value of the dropdown and send the ajax directly. Just add

```
id='anchor'
```

in a tag,

```
id="dropdown" onclick='getSelectedValue()'
```

on the select tag and add below script

```
function getSelectedValue() {
var e = document.getElementById("dropdown");
option= e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById("anchor").href="iframe_content.php?selection="+option;
return true;
```

}

Comment: Works fine. Though your explenation lacks mentioning to add id="dropdown" to the select tag. And also change "on the button" to "on the select tag". Then I will approve your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

on your anchor add a click listener and update href element yourself

```
document.getElementById("anchor").onclick = function() { 
document.getElementById("anchor").href="iframe_content.php?selection=" + document.getElementById('selection').value;
 return true;
 };
```